# Search single entity which is presented by multiple rows SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have `User` table which contains same user represented by different entities all around. For example

```
User Table
==========================
id         name
1          John Doe       
2          Doe, John
3          Nicholas Cage
4          BlackRiderXXX
5          Nicholas cage
```

where users `John Doe`, `Doe, John`, `BlackRiderXXX` are the same people. Also, `Nicholas Cage` and `Nicholas cage` are the same people. Other tables refer to user.id randomly based on which user object did the action.

For `Action` table it'll look like

```
Action Table
==========================
id         user_id      some_other_stuff 
1          1            ...
2          2            ...
3          1            ...
4          4            ...
5          3            ...
```

Where the actions 1,2,3,4 are all done by John Doe.

I'll have these users merged by the user manually meaning we'd know who is whom. They'd also select which User is the one they'd like to be as their main user account so we need to know this information as well.

I'm simplifiying a bit but I have a dozen tables which are like the Action table I provided above. We have mainly two use cases on how we will need to query:

1) Find actions which are done by user X (which should check all the users entities belonging to user X)
2) Find actions and group unique users

Main point is we will be using it everywhere around the codebase on 100+ queries so we want to design it well. How can I construct a system where the query will be simple enough also powerful enough to handle different querying ways?

Thanks

PS: We are using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

Why not include the "main" user in the first table?

User Table

```
id         name              main_user_id
1          John Doe               1
2          Doe, John              1
3          Nicholas Cage          2
4          BlackRiderXXX          1
5          Nicholas cage          2
```

Then you would join on:

```
select . . .
from actions a join
     users u
     on a.user_id = u.id
where u.main_user_id = 1;
```

If you want this selectable per *end user*, then use a different table:

```
create table end_user_users (
    end_user_users_id serial primary key,
    end_user_id int references end_users (end_user_id),
    end_user_user_id int references users (id),
    end_user_main_user_id int references users (id)
);
```

Then the query would look like:

```
select . . .
from actions a join
     end_users_users euu
     on euu.end_user_user_id = a.user_id and
        euu.end_user_id = $my_id
where euu.end_user_main_user_id = 1;
```

Comment: Could you clarify the second one with `per end user`. I did not get what `end_user` and `end_end_user` represents.

Comment: @Thellimist . . . "They'd also select which User is the one they'd like to be as their main user account so we need to know this information as well."  I do not know if this applies to end users choosing the main user for all "users" in the database or only for the multiples that apply to that user.  If the latter, then the first solution is what you want.

Comment: Yes, it's the latter is what I wanted to say

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_replace()`,`initcap()` and `trim()` functions to refine and extract the common name strings to be grouped, and then generate values for newly created `action_id` column depending on them :

```
with new_action0 as
(
select u.id as id,
       case when strpos(u.name,',') > 0 then
            initcap(trim(regexp_replace(trim(u.name),'(.*),(.*)','\2 \1')))
       else  
           case when lower(trim(u.name))='blackriderxxx' then
                'John Doe'
           else
                trim(initcap(u.name))
           end 
       end as name
  from action u 
)
select n.id, dense_rank() over (order by n.name) as user_id
  from new_action0 n;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d6733bf491fe3860262f2021281189aa)</kbd>

A new decent user table can be created by using this query with `create table .. as` statement

Comment: I like the idea, however, this seem quite manual. There will be 100s of thousands of users whose name should be replaced

Comment: Hi @Thellimist. Well, I coudn't understand what you expect to get more by sharing only this much sample data.